# are hover links available on feed-based page layout?

Tags: administration, page-layout, configuration

In the good ol' days, when I looked at an opportunity page layout I would be able to see the hover links for the related lists associated to the record. However, now I notice that they are no longer visible when I create a new feed-based page layout for same. Is there a way of getting them back?

Comment: I can't believe I am saying this, but this question is probably best suited for the Salesforce Success Community. While I am sure that many users here could find/know the answer, the Salesforce Answers Community would love to see this question and would probably have some great insights.

Comment: I don't know whether to vote up on down your comment on the basis that it provides an option for directing traffic away from this site but also your honesty is appreciated! (smiley face goes here)